# How to use HtmlUnit with Tor?

Tags: java, htmlunit, tor

I want to use HtmlUnit with Tor. But I can't connect to Tor with HtmlUnit (I have Tor Browser Bundle running). I read on the TOR documentation that I can use Tor with other aplications by a socks proxy on localhost:9050.

I can connect to a normal proxy found on google with this code:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();      
ProxyConfig prc = new ProxyConfig("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 8081, false);
webClient.getOptions().setProxyConfig(prc); 
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://whatismyipaddress.com");          
System.out.print(page.asText());
```

But if I replace the ip and port with localhost and 9050, then it's not working:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();      
ProxyConfig prc = new ProxyConfig("localhost", 9050, true);
webClient.getOptions().setProxyConfig(prc); 
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://whatismyipaddress.com");          
System.out.print(page.asText());
```

Comment: Maybe SOCKS is not supported ?

Comment: @Peter: the last parameter of the ProxyConfig constructor is "isSocks" so I think it supports SOCKS.

Comment: Did you get any message or only a timeout ?

Comment: @Peter: I get the following error: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: Connection refused: connect

Comment: Seems that localhost is not listening on port 9050 or your firewall avoid connecting.

Answer (score 2):

Found out the problem: the port number is 9150, not 9050. No idea why they say 9050 in the documentation.